# Is there a public shapefile with the London Underground stations and lines?

Tags: shapefile, data

Is there a public shapefile containing the stations and lines of the London Underground? I've been doing some intensive searching but I can only find the coordinates of the stations, or the lines in way too much detail on OpenSteeetMap.

Ideally, I want each line to have a single track, not multiple like with OSM.

Comment: Are we talking geographical (physical) or TopoLOGICal version? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_map

Comment: KML file here - http://www.doogal.co.uk/london_stations.php

Comment: KML2Shapefile here http://www.zonums.com/online/kml2shp.php

Answer (score 15):

Ordnance Survey's VectorMap District has a shapefile that contains Underground stations - it's within the "RailwayStation" file but you can filter on the "CLASSIFICA" field. The website is http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-vectormap-district/index.html and the licence is based on the Open Government Licence http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/opendata/licensing.html. The data is from March 2011 though so could be out of date! Unfortunately I can't see any line information in the OS open products.

Answer (score 6):

TFL (Transport for London) do have a lot of data that is available for Developers, one of the datasets is Stattions Locations.

The website is here

http://www.tfl.gov.uk/businessandpartners/syndication/16492.aspx

I would read the T&Cs and check to find out if the data you need can be used for your application

Comment: The link is broken unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

There is also a github project with stats and data layers in geoJSON format

[Github: Mapped-based data visualisations](https://github.com/oobrien/vis)

Specifically the files [here](https://github.com/oobrien/vis/tree/master/tube/data)

Comment: Could you please add more details to your answer, such as explaining what this project precisely does?

Comment: @ArMoraer the project is irrelevant. The OP wanted a shapefile of London Underground station etc and this project has geoJSON that is IMO better than a shapefile. I've edited the answer to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the .json from the previous comment ([Github: Mapped-based data visualizations](https://github.com/oobrien/vis)) and tried to get it into spatial object in geopandas, but I found that the station information is nested inside each feature.

So if anyone is still looking for a spatial file of London tube, I have extracted some of the information and cleaned it for use in GIS or graph and saved the file, along with the Python code to clean it on [Github](https://github.com/lenkahas/London_tube_spatial_files).

I do realise my cleaning process is not the most straightforward option, so if anyone has better way, let me know.